# Azure ML Studio Docker Endpoint Deployment Error 400 Client Error

Tags: python, azure-machine-learning-service

I would like to deploy an ML endpoint (first locally to see the error messages) from custom environment. But I am getting the following error message. Can anybody clarify what does this stands for?

The environment deployment is fine, I can pull and play with the environment image, the the ML model also works as it expected, but in the endpoint development I fail.

```
from azureml.core.model import InferenceConfig, Model
from azureml.core.webservice import AciWebservice, LocalWebservice

ocr_model = Model(name='OCR_model', workspace=workspace)
quality_model = Model(name='Quality_model', workspace=workspace)
inference_config = InferenceConfig(entry_script="ml_scores.py", environment=python_env)
deployment_config = LocalWebservice.deploy_configuration(port=6789)

service = Model.deploy(workspace=workspace,
                       name="ml-service-v2",
                       overwrite=True,
                       models=[ocr_model, quality_model],
                       inference_config=inference_config,
                       deployment_config=deployment_config)

service.wait_for_deployment(show_output=True)
```

The error message:

```
Warning, custom base image or base dockerfile detected without a specified `inferencing_stack_version`. Please set environment.inferencing_stack_version='latest'
Warning, custom base image or base dockerfile detected without a specified `inferencing_stack_version`. Please set environment.inferencing_stack_version='latest'
Docker container start has failed:
400 Client Error for http+docker://localhost/v1.41/containers/f4ee0f109af60a21a11683dd3d69db87b6371b2c3b038ea0227a8cc8422c4200/start: Bad Request ("failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "runsvdir": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown")

Downloading model OCR_model:42 to /tmp/azureml_25emn1le/OCR_model/42
Downloading model Quality_model:40 to /tmp/azureml_25emn1le/Quality_model/40
Generating Docker build context.
Package creation Succeeded
Logging into Docker registry 088e52be0d7942c4a6e11258fa37a140.azurecr.io
Logging into Docker registry 088e52be0d7942c4a6e11258fa37a140.azurecr.io
Building Docker image from Dockerfile...
Step 1/5 : FROM 088e52be0d7942c4a6e11258fa37a140.azurecr.io/azureml/azureml_152ffef9bfdf00715d63c8352ff2cc66
 ---> 31b97aac1e18
Step 2/5 : COPY azureml-app /var/azureml-app
 ---> a31c2d80deb2
Step 3/5 : RUN mkdir -p '/var/azureml-app' && echo eyJhY2NvdW50Q29udGV4dCI6eyJzdWJzY3JpcHRpb25JZCI6IjIwMjQ0MjYwLWQyY2ItNDNkMy05NjZlLWQwZjcyMDE3ZWJhMCIsInJlc291cmNlR3JvdXBOYW1lIjoibWxfYmV0YV9yZyIsImFjY291bnROYW1lIjoibWFjaGluZS1sZWFybmluZy1iZXRhLXdzIiwid29ya3NwYWNlSWQiOiIwODhlNTJiZS0wZDc5LTQyYzQtYTZlMS0xMjU4ZmEzN2ExNDAifSwibW9kZWxzIjp7fSwibW9kZWxzSW5mbyI6e319 | base64 --decode > /var/azureml-app/model_config_map.json
 ---> Running in 783f521ea037
 ---> 8900434882b2
Step 4/5 : RUN mv '/var/azureml-app/tmpdswbb3xk.py' /var/azureml-app/main.py
 ---> Running in 8b61d3f35a90
 ---> 05890493cdd1
Step 5/5 : CMD ["runsvdir","/var/runit"]
 ---> Running in 052ae96b5d75
 ---> b15b8dfb9deb
Successfully built b15b8dfb9deb
Successfully tagged ml-service-v2:latest
Container (name:xenodochial_goldwasser, id:2757f295fa1836dd83d2dcb162ccbb566c04cba1f3fb0c35943f5d4d101d5479) cannot be killed.
Container has been successfully cleaned up.
Image sha256:ed2b4e50c397597d857883a76e5d53a5c27ce700894d3b2f7167d477f7b82be2 successfully removed.
Starting Docker container...
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
HTTPError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
File /anaconda/envs/azureml_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/docker/api/client.py:268, in APIClient._raise_for_status(self, response)
    267 try:
--> 268     response.raise_for_status()
    269 except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as e:

File /anaconda/envs/azureml_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/models.py:1021, in Response.raise_for_status(self)
   1020 if http_error_msg:
-> 1021     raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)

HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: http+docker://localhost/v1.41/containers/f4ee0f109af60a21a11683dd3d69db87b6371b2c3b038ea0227a8cc8422c4200/start

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

APIError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
File /anaconda/envs/azureml_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azureml/_model_management/_util.py:495, in start_docker_container(container)
    493 print("Starting Docker container...")
--> 495 container.start()
    497 print('Docker container running.')

File /anaconda/envs/azureml_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/docker/models/containers.py:404, in Container.start(self, **kwargs)
    396 """
    397 Start this container. Similar to the ``docker start`` command, but
    398 doesn't support attach options.
   (...)
    402         If the server returns an error.
    403 """
--> 404 return self.client.api.start(self.id, **kwargs)

File /anaconda/envs/azureml_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/docker/utils/decorators.py:19, in check_resource.<locals>.decorator.<locals>.wrapped(self, resource_id, *args, **kwargs)
     16     raise errors.NullResource(
     17         'Resource ID was not provided'
     18     )
---> 19 return f(self, resource_id, *args, **kwargs)

File /anaconda/envs/azureml_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/docker/api/container.py:1109, in ContainerApiMixin.start(self, container, *args, **kwargs)
   1108 res = self._post(url)
-> 1109 self._raise_for_status(res)

File /anaconda/envs/azureml_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/docker/api/client.py:270, in APIClient._raise_for_status(self, response)
    269 except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as e:
--> 270     raise create_api_error_from_http_exception(e)

File /anaconda/envs/azureml_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/docker/errors.py:31, in create_api_error_from_http_exception(e)
     30         cls = NotFound
---> 31 raise cls(e, response=response, explanation=explanation)

APIError: 400 Client Error for http+docker://localhost/v1.41/containers/f4ee0f109af60a21a11683dd3d69db87b6371b2c3b038ea0227a8cc8422c4200/start: Bad Request ("failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "runsvdir": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown")

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

WebserviceException                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [20], in <cell line: 12>()
      9 # deployment_config = AciWebservice.deploy_configuration(cpu_cores=2, memory_gb=4)
     10 deployment_config = LocalWebservice.deploy_configuration(port=6789)
---> 12 service = Model.deploy(workspace=workspace,
     13                        name="ml-service-v2",
     14                        overwrite=True,
     15                        models=[ocr_model, quality_model],
     16                        inference_config=inference_config,
     17                        deployment_config=deployment_config)
     19 service.wait_for_deployment(show_output=True)

File /anaconda/envs/azureml_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azureml/core/model.py:1649, in Model.deploy(workspace, name, models, inference_config, deployment_config, deployment_target, overwrite, show_output)
   1647 # Local webservice.
   1648 if deployment_config and isinstance(deployment_config, LocalWebserviceDeploymentConfiguration):
-> 1649     return deployment_config._webservice_type._deploy(workspace, name, models,
   1650                                                       inference_config=inference_config,
   1651                                                       deployment_config=deployment_config)
   1653 # IotWebservice does not support environment-style deployment,
   1654 # so make sure we don't deploy IotWebservice with environment;
   1655 # We only support ACI, AKS, AKS endpoint, and MIR for now.
   1656 from azureml._model_management._constants import IOT_WEBSERVICE_TYPE

File /anaconda/envs/azureml_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azureml/core/webservice/local.py:739, in LocalWebservice._deploy(workspace, name, models, image_config, deployment_config, wait, inference_config)
    735     raise WebserviceException('Error, provided inference configuration must be of type InferenceConfig '
    736                               'in order to deploy a local service.', logger=module_logger)
    738 service = LocalWebservice(workspace, name, must_exist=False)
--> 739 service.update(models=models,
    740                image_config=image_config,
    741                inference_config=inference_config,
    742                deployment_config=deployment_config,
    743                wait=wait)
    744 return service

File /anaconda/envs/azureml_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azureml/core/webservice/local.py:72, in _in_state.<locals>.decorator.<locals>.decorated(self, *args, **kwargs)
     69 if self.state not in states:
     70     raise WebserviceException('Cannot call {}() when service is {}.'.format(func.__name__, self.state),
     71                               logger=module_logger)
---> 72 return func(self, *args, **kwargs)

File /anaconda/envs/azureml_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azureml/core/webservice/local.py:549, in LocalWebservice.update(self, models, image_config, deployment_config, wait, inference_config)
    547 self._generate_docker_context()
    548 self._build_image()
--> 549 self._run_container(wait=wait)

File /anaconda/envs/azureml_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azureml/core/webservice/local.py:1021, in LocalWebservice._run_container(self, wait)
   1018         LocalWebservice._copy_local_asset(container, self._inference_config.entry_script)
   1020 # Engage!
-> 1021 start_docker_container(container)
   1023 # Record the state of the deployment.
   1024 self._container = container

File /anaconda/envs/azureml_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azureml/_model_management/_util.py:503, in start_docker_container(container)
    500     raise WebserviceException('Docker container start has failed, the port you are attempting to use '
    501                               'is already in use:\n{}'.format(e), logger=module_logger)
    502 else:
--> 503     raise WebserviceException('Docker container start has failed:\n{}'.format(e), logger=module_logger)

WebserviceException: WebserviceException:
    Message: Docker container start has failed:
400 Client Error for http+docker://localhost/v1.41/containers/f4ee0f109af60a21a11683dd3d69db87b6371b2c3b038ea0227a8cc8422c4200/start: Bad Request ("failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "runsvdir": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown")
    InnerException None
    ErrorResponse 
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Docker container start has failed:\n400 Client Error for http+docker://localhost/v1.41/containers/f4ee0f109af60a21a11683dd3d69db87b6371b2c3b038ea0227a8cc8422c4200/start: Bad Request (\"failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: \"runsvdir\": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown\")"
    }
}
```

Thanks for any kind of guidance!

Comment: When the model is registered once, with the environment variables in the app registration, then we cannot reregister the model with the same endpoint. The environment variables and the Endpoints information are fixed. When we cannot register the new model which is available already with specific endpoints and 400 bad request is because docker file recognized the duplicate variables.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. It turns out that `runit` is a linux utility, and it was not included in the base image I was using. It can be installed directly with the commands below:

```
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y upgrade
RUN apt-get install -y runit runit-systemd
```

However, in order to run, Azure ML requires a number of other custom scripts. As a result, the best way to create your own images is to start with one of the pre-built images that Azure provides, e.g.: `mcr.microsoft.com/azureml/minimal-ubuntu20.04-py38-cpu-inference:latest`

This image will include both the utility above, as well as the directory `/var/runit` that is being passed as an argument to `runsvdir`.